# how to apply/merge a feature branch onto a newer release branch?

Tags: git

Let us consider this situation:

```
---A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I---J---  (master from upstream)
       \                    \
        D'--F'               J'              (releases from upstream)
             \
              P---Q                          (own branch)
```

We want to have merged or patched all of our own branch onto J'.

When P---Q would have been a direct descendant of the master branch, I do not encounter much trouble. However, with this use case I get many merge conflicts related to files that are not touched in my own branch. These conflicts originate from the D'---F' part in this example.
So I generated a diff from F'---Q, and tried to git apply this onto J'. Result: many apply errors.
Another approach, git-format-patch F'---Q and then git am -3 -k doesn't prove to be an efficient solution either. Effectively, this is much comparable to the merge solution. I also tried rebase. Again: many files that I didn't touch appear in the rebasing process.

Any clean solution available?

Comment: Shouldn't you rebase your own development back to master first, before dealing with release branch? And, from my previous experiences on other SCM, we should only use release branch to capture changesets from master (for maintenance release).  Feature branch should be branched from the branch for development (master in your case) instead from release branch.  That will make the whole story easier to handle

Comment: Well, to be precise: my feature branch is in fact a set of kernel modifications to drivers etc. that make up a linux kernel for own purpose, but a desired release quality. This is the reason why I went to base my branch on a release branch rather than the master. I also did this because of increasing git experience. I simply didn't expect that git would complain about files that I didnt' touch.

Comment: Regarding your idea (rebase back): I also considered this, but decided to first ask this question, because a dual step process sounds complicated. It is already painful enough to update my own branch to a substantially newer kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

I began to realize that the number of commits, generated by a git format-patch was far more than strictly necessary. Dealing with this and format-patch a smaller commit range resulted in far better handling the git am iterations. In order to explain what is going on, I extend the graph:

```
---A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I---J---  (master from upstream)
    \   \                    \
     \   D'--F'               J'              (releases from upstream)
      \       \
       M---N---P---Q                          (own branch)
```

M--N were former commits, based upon master. P is a merged commit, so

```
git format-patch F'..Q
```

results in a patch series far deeper in history (my case: approx. 60), and very strange git am iterations. When the format-patch P---Q is used, I get approx. 30 commits (indeed, P---Q is a simplification). Now git am iterations results in git mergetool steps which have a clear relationship with the commits since P, and were manageable.